# Creating a child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am trying to create a child theme but I think that there is something wrong with my functions.php.

```
(<?php)add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'sydney', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}function theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'sydney';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'sydney-child',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0):

May Be this problem is due to function.php file in your child theme.

Child theme’s functions.php is loaded first implies that you can create the user functions of your theme pluggable - that are replaceable by a child theme - by mentioning them restrictively. E.g.:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_special_nav' ) ) {
    function theme_special_nav() {
        //  Do something.
    }
}
```

In that way, a child theme can replace a PHP function of the parent by simply declaring it beforehand.

for further reference please visit : [Wordpress Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

If you find my answer helpful please mark it, So others can take the benefits of it.